# How to get none matching columns and matching columns with two sql tables

Tags: mysql, sql, date, group-by, sum

I have two table incomes and expenses, I want to includes the none matching columns to the third table so I can be able to sum and group incomes and expenses with months and sum the Income column to get total and Expense Column total

```
             incomes table                                 expenses table
    -----------------------------------        ------------------------------------
    | incomeId |    date     | amount |        | expenseId |    date     | amount |
    +---------------------------------+        +----------------------------------+
    | 1        | 2/4/2020    | 3000   |        |  1        | 8/4/2020    | 3000   | 
    | 2        | 9/4/2020    | 9000   |        |  2        | 23/4/2020   | 3500   |
    | 3        | 15/9/2020   | 15000  |        |  1        | 9/3/2020    | 2000   |
    | 4        | 7/3/2020    | 7000   |        ------------------------------------
    ------------------------------------


                 Expected table Results
        ------------------------------------
        | Month     | Income     | Expense |
        +----------------------------------+
        | March     | 7000       | 2000    | 
        | April     | 12000      | 6500    |
        | September | 15000      |         |
        +==================================+
        | Total     | 34000      |  8500   |
        ====================================
```

SQL

```
  SELECT 
        Income.Month, 
        Income.Income, 
        Expense.Expense
      FROM(
            SELECT 
                DATE_FORMAT(date,'%M') AS Month, 
                SUM(amount) AS Income
            FROM income
            GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%M')
           ) AS Incomes
      JOIN
          (
            SELECT
                  DATE_FORMAT(date,'%M') AS Month,
                  SUM(amount) AS Expense
            FROM expenses
            GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%M') 
          ) AS Expense
       ON Expense.Month = Income.Month
```

Comment: Have you tried a  LEFT JOIN?

Comment: Yes but, But it hides month on columns that do not have mactched values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to allow missing dates on both tables, you can emulate a `full join` with `union all`:

```
select year(date) yr, month(date) mn, sum(income) income, sum(expense) expense
from (
    select date, amount income, null expense from incomes
    union all
    select date, null, amount from expenses
) t
group by year(date), month(date)
with rollup
```

Comment: Thank you very much @GMB, i can see all data now, the problem is, for the null columns it display the same amount on both icome and expense column, How can I solve this because I want to calculate total incomes and total expense for all months How can I do that?